# How to add multiple value to a dictionary key in Python

Tags: python

I am new to python.

```
list = {('9034','1234'):'BMW', '9996':'Chevy', '7206':'Ford'}
x = raw_input("Enter first 4 digit: ")
print (list[(x)])
```

How can i print BMW in both value '9034' and '1234'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just have two separate entries for it.

```
list = {'9034': 'BMW', '1234': 'BMW', '9996': 'Chevy', '7206': 'Ford'}
x = raw_input("Enter first 4 digit: ")
print(list[x])
```

Also, please consider renaming list to something else since `list` is an object type and built-in name in Python.

Comment: Thank you, i will rename it. And also i have more than 50 value for 'BMW' so do i have to write all of them individually ?

Comment: Yes. There's nothing bad about letting your dictionary have 50 unique keys pointing to 'BMW'.

Comment: And how can i print 'Not Found' if i enter a value which is not in the dictionary ?

Comment: You can check if key is contained in your dictionary with `'1234' in dict_name`. Or for this particular code you could do `print(list.get('9900', 'Not Found'))`. It will print 'Not Found' if '9900' is not a key in dictionary.